# Compatibility mode issue

Tags: browser-compatibility

I am trying to edit a document in the sharepoint and on the page above it shows me the message: "Compatibility Mode. Functionality is currently limited". Could you please tell me what that means?

Thank you

Emmanouela

Comment: you might want to explain which browser you are using

Comment: It is unclear to me where exactly the error message appears. Could you please post a Screenshot of the message.